# Last week VS Past week VS Previous week

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

What's the difference between them? When should I use each?

I always try to give some info or context, but I do have no idea which I should use.

Thank you.

Comment: Does anything at [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/160765/past-year-vs-last-year-vs-previous-year) help?

Comment: They also help me a lot, Gotube. Thank you. :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"This week" means "in the seven days that started on Sunday and will end on Saturday"  (or sometimes Monday to Sunday)

> This week I played tennis on Monday, and I will play golf on Friday.

And "Last week" means the week that ended on Saturday.

```
 <last week> | <This week>
S M T W T H S S M T W T H S
                    ^
                 today
```

You don't use "past week" very much, but you can have an expression like "during the past week".  It could mean "In the seven days until now, but it would most likely be used near the end of a week to mean "The part of this this week that has past". So on Friday you might say

> In the past week we have made good progress

To mean "From Monday to Thusday this week, we have made good progress".

You would use "previous" week with some particular reference to what it was previous to:

> Christmas will be a holiday, and in the previous week (ie previous to Christmas) staff will be permitted to finish at 4)

Comment: James, I'll look carefully at your answer this morning! Thank you very much for now, friend.